# Exclude comma character from a non-whitespace string

Tags: regex, whitespace

I need a regex expression that will validate that a string is not all whitespace and that it does not include the comma (,) character.

I've been able to find examples that do one or the other, but not both:

`^(?![\s,]*$).+` to insure not all white space and
`^(.(?!,))*$` to exclude commas.

I don't have the option of using code, this is a constraint on a field in a form.

Comment: `"I've been able to find examples"` - it may help to show them. This also proves that you did something and generally makes people friendlier.

Comment: The negative lookahead to resolve the commas is unusual.  Normally, you'd write `^[^,]*$`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should suit your needs:

```
^[^,]*[^ ,][^,]*$
```

*"At least one char that is not a space nor a comma, surrounded by any char but a comma"*